# How to Parceable a object that has a List<CustomObject>

Tags: java, android

I have a Class Episode that has a Array List of Person objects. When I parseable the Episode object i can successfully get the data, but not the Lists.

Episode Class Code that implements Parseable:

```java
protected Episode(Parcel in) {
        id = in.readInt();
        number = in.readInt();
        seasonNumber = in.readInt();
        rating = in.readDouble();
        name = in.readString();
        overview = in.readString();
        date = in.readString();
        image = in.readString();
        crew = in.createTypedArrayList(Person.CREATOR);
        guestStars = in.createTypedArrayList(Person.CREATOR);
    }

    public static final Creator<Episode> CREATOR = new Creator<Episode>() {
        @Override
        public Episode createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Episode(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Episode[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Episode[size];
        }
    };

@Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(id);
        dest.writeInt(number);
        dest.writeInt(seasonNumber);
        dest.writeDouble(rating);
        dest.writeString(name);
        dest.writeString(overview);
        dest.writeString(date);
        dest.writeString(image);
        dest.writeTypedList(crew);
        dest.writeTypedList(guestStars);
    }
```

The Person Class that also implements Parseable:

```java
protected Person(Parcel in) {
        id = in.readInt();
        name = in.readString();
        creditId = in.readString();
        gender = in.readString();
        profile = in.readString();
        character = in.readString();
        department = in.readString();
        job = in.readString();
    }

    public static final Creator<Person> CREATOR = new Creator<Person>() {
        @Override
        public Person createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Person(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Person[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Person[size];
        }
    };

@Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(id);
        dest.writeString(name);
        dest.writeString(creditId);
        dest.writeString(gender);
        dest.writeString(profile);
        dest.writeString(character);
        dest.writeString(department);
        dest.writeString(job);
    }
```

Where did I make a mistake to not be able to get the list of Person?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Above is Correct. I just made a simple mistake of not displaying the data properly.